# Colorbox fails to open or add cbox class

Tags: jquery, colorbox, anythingslider

I've got an `<a href="">` which targets a hidden `<div>`. I'm loading the hidden HTML content into the popup modal window but my link always goes through to the homepage (baseurl).

http://coolicebox.petersenuploads.co.uk/product.php?xProd=2&xSec=5

See the link in the Options panel (see more colours)

It looks like the cbox class isn't being added to the link but I can't for the life of me see why it's not running? The code is there and being called but no class added hence the link goes to the root of the site.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element was in the HTML by the time document.ready() but there was a problem with the preceding call to 'anything-slider'. I've since commented it as follows to check if the slider exists before doing anything else. Now works. Thanks for your help and advice Andy, even if it wasn't the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if($('#slider').length > 0) {
    $('#slider')
        .anythingSlider({
            navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){
                return ['Slab', 'Parking Lot', 'Drive', 'Glorius Dawn', 'Bjork?', 'Traffic Circle'][index - 1];
            },
            buildStartStop: false,
            buildNavigation: true,
            autoPlay: true
        })
        .anythingSliderFx({
            '.caption-top'    : [ 'caption-Top', '50px' ],
        })
}
//Add modal functionality where class is set
$('.modal-inline').colorbox({transition:'elastic', speed:500, width:'80%', height:'50%', inline:true});
$('.modal-image').colorbox({transition:'elastic', speed:500, width:'80%', height:'50%', inline:false});
$('.modal-image-square').colorbox({transition:'elastic', speed:500, width:'1000', height:'1000', inline:false});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the

```
$('.modal-inline').unbind('click').colorbox({transition:'elastic', speed:500, width:'80%', height:'50%', inline:true});
```

is being executed. I put a breakpoint on it and it did not stop.

For some reason the `$('.model-inline')` selector is not finding any elements to make into a colorbox. So are you adding the element dynamically after the selector has already executed?

If you drop into the Chrome Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> on Windows) and enter

```
$('.modal-inline').unbind('click').colorbox({transition:'elastic', speed:500, width:'80%', height:'50%', inline:true});
```

and then click the link, then it works!

Another factor *could* be because the page is [not valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://coolicebox.petersenuploads.co.uk/product.php?xProd=2&xSec=5&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) but I've not seen this sort of thing happen before because of invalid mark-up.

Comment: I've fixed as many validation errors as possible. The remaining ones are related to Cloudzoom and it's large rel="" attribute. Could something be hijacking it? I've used colorbox on these types of sites before and not had a problem. Could it be a jquery version problem?

Comment: Unfortunately the page now has a UTF-8 error (probably the `£` which is showing up as a missing character now). The validator cannot parse non-UTF-8 bytes. Also could you say whether the `<a>` that you are attempting to bind `.colorbox()` to is added dynamically or is part of the page generated by PHP?

Comment: Furthermore, the jQuery version in your page is the same as in the colorbox examples, so it's not a jQuery version problem. Disabling the other plugins is a good approach to narrowing down the issue but I really still think that because the binding is successful when done in the Console but it is not working in the `$(document).ready();` which just sounds like the element you want to bind does not exist at that time

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site using Chrome's DevTools confirms @andyb's assertion: there are **no event listener's attached** to the  tag of class 'modal-inline'.

Why are you executing the 'unbind' method on that link?  ColorBox handles its own click event binding's for you.

- Kevin M.